# I am working in Microsoft excel and have questions with my countif/countifs function

Tags: excel, countif

I am working on a project to calculate the percentage of yes responses to specific questions. The options include "Yes", "No" and "N/A". I would like to calculate the percentage of Yes for applicable scenarios. I.E.:

Did the representative resolve the issue: Yes, No, or N/A

I would like N/A to be removed from the calculation.

In 5 examples the representative had 3 yes's, 1 No and 1 N/A
In real life this would equate to a 75% resolve rate (which is what i am seeking), In my spreadsheet it equates to 60% "yes". Here is my countif equation:

=IFERROR(COUNTIF(C5:G5, "Yes")/COUNTA(C5:G5),"-")

Comment: =countif(c5:g5,"Yes") / (countif(c5:g5,"Yes")+countif(c5:g5,"No"))

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
= countif(c5:g5,"Yes") / ( counta(C5:G5)- countif(c5:g5,"N/A") )
```